# Creating a streaming site like twitch, or ustream?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, streaming

I'm curious as to how to go about creating a website like twitch.tv, justin.tv, ustream, etc.

I have a lot of experience with PHP, jquery, MySQL, flash, etc. I am a very well rounded web developer.

Basically I just want to know where to get started. Is there some type of open source solution I can use to get started? What will this entail? I'm assuming I need to create a script that accept incoming streams and then displays their data seperately so people can have their own profiles and whatnot.

Like I said I have no clue where to get started so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: way to B R O A D for a S.O question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From previous googleling i found some useful information so i am sharing it to you.

You can take advantage of `Comet Programming` to accomplish your task. But problem is that you never found any useful `example` for that.

Comet is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it. [**more words on comet**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

You can also use `Ajax long-polling` hitting server over periodic time and check for updates this techniques broadly used. [**Some more**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Also you can use `server side scripting javascript`. One of the best known and widely used js is `node.js`. [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/).

1. **Node.js** - A backend server that can use sockets to deliver real time updates to the browser.
2. **Backbone.js** - A semi structured way of building single page applications "like gmail"

I'd also include Require.js to that list which is basically used to load all the Backbone javascript files asynchronously. It helps to keep the file structure of your application maintainable.

Example i found useful when i started learning about [**comet**](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start).